# Wrap text inside html tag

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to wrap text in inside `<span>` tag using jQuery. The below code is not working. Please point out where I am going wrong. Also please suggest a better/different approach.

```
var mysearch = '(05/13/2012-11/13/2012)';
$('table:eq(0) tr:eq(1) th:contains("' + mysearch + '")').filter(function () {
    return this.html().replace('(05/13/2012-11/13/2012)', '<span class = "red"> (05/13/2012-11/13/2012)</span>');
});
```

[Demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8kMqW/)

Comment: can you make a fiddle of your issue

Answer (score 5):

`this` in your code is a DOM Element object that doesn't have `html` method, also you don't need the `filter` method, you can use `html` method.

```
$('table:eq(0) tr:eq(1) th:contains("' + mysearch + '")').html(function(_, html) {
    return html.replace('(05/13/2012-11/13/2012)', '<span class="red"> (05/13/2012-11/13/2012)</span>');
});
```

If the content of the `th` is equal to `mysearch` string, you can also use `wrapInner` method:

```
$('table:eq(0) tr:eq(1) th').filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).text()) === mysearch;
}).wrapInner('<span class="red"></span>');
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QMEk7/)

Comment: Deleted my own answer, as I hadn't noticed the use of `filter()` in place of `html()` (and improving my answer would, necessarily, have plagiarised (or at least *repeated*) your own). Plus-one to you, sir!

Comment: Thank u. But i don't see the text being wrapped in span even after apply ur code.

Comment: @DavidThomas Oh, yes, OP's code uses `filter` method, Thank you.

Comment: @BumbleBee You are welcome, can you provide a demo on http://www.jsfiddle.net? Have you put the code in document ready handler?

Comment: @TryTryAgain Thank-you for the demo. But that's not the suggested code in my answer.

Comment: @undefined sorry, I just added a link description, I was not sure of the validity as BumbleBee posted it but didn't enter a hyperlink name ... see: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16549754/revisions

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
$('table:eq(0) th:contains("' + mysearch + '")').contents().wrapAll('<span class = "red"></span>');
```

Working Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/8kMqW/2/

Comment: Thank u. But i don't see the text being wrapped in span even after apply ur code.

Comment: thank u. I want only the text of "mysearch" to be wrapped in <span> not the entire text.